# Does networkx keep track of node depths?

Tags: python, networkx

Does anyone know if python networkx pre-computes node depths for a tree created using a Networkx DiGraph?

Since I have not seen a way to define trees in networkx, maybe it would be necessary to just  compute the node depths using an external data structure.

Answer (score 12):

If you know the root of the tree you can use the shortest_path() function to get the distance from the root:

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.DiGraph()

In [3]: G.add_path([0,10,20,30])

In [4]: G.add_path([0,1,2,3])

In [5]: nx.shortest_path_length(G,0) # assume a tree rooted at node 0
Out[5]: {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 10: 1, 20: 2, 30: 3}
```